# Word mail merge and page breaks

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, mail-merge

Looking for a way to put a page break after a number of rows in an Excel data source for mail merge in Word - the number of rows before the page break can vary, depending on he number of records that are associated with a particular client.

My logic tells me I have to put the break in the data source (Excel), but Word seems to ignore that.

Comment: Can you put the page break in the Word template just after the last merge field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find the solution for this, and ended up making the merge as labels of 20 per page, and then rounded the number of tickets up to multiples of 20 (e.g., if a partner needed to get 15 tickets, I printed one page, if 21 tickets, 2 pages, etc. This was not ideal but solved the problem with minimum effort.